# Sheet Best API - How to add data to a specified sheet using a post request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, axios

Currently working on a project that is utilizing the Sheet Best API to send data directly to my Google Sheets. The issue that I am having is that when I submit the data it is only going to one (the first one only) sheet. I currently have 3 different forms on the site and I want it to match up with the 3 Google Sheets that I have setup currently. I am using axios to make my request. Is there not a feature that allows this or am I just simply missing something in my request? Below is just a simple post request, again it's only going to the first spreadsheet only out of the 3 and I need to control which sheet it goes. All of the basic settings are in place aka the have the same permissions and share link value to input into Sheet Best system.

```js
const submitForm = (data) => {
    // data.date = new Date();
    console.log(data);
    axios.post("https://sheet.best/api/sheets/MY-API-KEY-FOR-SHEET-BEST-HERE", data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after searching their docs a little bit more. There is a section for anyone else that may have this issue (or completely missed it like me) regarding "Working with Different Tabs" section of their documentation. Simply put, at the end of the request string insert "tabs/NAME-OF-YOUR-TAB" in order to work with that exact sheet/tab that you are wanting to manage data from.

Ex:

```js
    const submitForm = (data) => {
        // data.date = new Date();
        console.log(data);
        axios.post("https://sheet.best/api/sheets/MY-API-KEY-FOR-SHEET-BEST-HERE/tabs/NAME-OF-THE-TAB", data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```